# What does §11.9 on ECMAScript standard says?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, standards

Following a previously closed [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389903/why-should-i-still-put-semicolons-on-my-javascript), I understand that I have to be more specific.

I have read the ECMAScript standard (ES6 and ES18) and the paragraph §11.9 got my attention. I noticed slightly changes between the two releases. But it appear unclear to me, perhaps because of my bad English.

Could someone explain me what are the main differences between these two standards, and how I should understand them?

We went from *certain statements* to *most statements* but it is also said that *For convenience, however, such semicolons may be omitted*. This looks contradictory to me.

What is the proper way to read this paragraph?

### §11.9 [ES-2015](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/ECMA-262.pdf)

> Certain ECMAScript statements (empty statement, `let`, `const`, `import`, and `export` declarations, variable statement, expression statement, `debugger` statement, `continue` statement, `break` statement, `return` statement, and `throw` statement) must be terminated with semicolons. Such semicolons may always appear explicitly in the source text. For convenience, however, such semicolons may be omitted from the source text in certain situations. These situations are described by saying that semicolons are automatically inserted into the source code token stream in those situations.

### §11.9 [ES-2018](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)

> Most ECMAScript statements and declarations must be terminated with a semicolon. Such semicolons may always appear explicitly in the source text. For convenience, however, such semicolons may be omitted from the source text in
>   certain situations. These situations are described by saying that semicolons are automatically inserted into the source code token stream in those situations.

Comment: The subsections 11.9.1 and 11.9.2 describe exactly how semicolon insertion works, as well as the "[No *Line Terminator* here]" markers in the grammar. The paragraph you quoted is the introduction to the whole section including the subsections.

Comment: I guess it's a little like filling out a deposit slip at the bank. Slips for all deposits need an account number, but if you don't write it in, the teller will do it for you in certain situations. Is the account number required? Yes. Do you need to fill it in? Not always.

Comment: The two paragraphs are saying essentially the same thing. They just decided not to list the statement types explicitly in the newer introduction, probably because the list was getting too long. The rules that follow provide the details.

Comment: I quickly scanned 11.9.1 in the two versions. As far as I can tell, nothing has changed significantly in the rules, but they've changed some of the names of productions (e.g. `PostfixExpression` became `UpdateExpression`). It looks like the differences are all editorial, not technical.

Comment: Your two questions seem to assume that something has changed regarding Automatic Semicolon Insertion. Nothing has changed except maybe opinions about whether it's a useful thing to depend on.

Comment: Yeah, the ECMAScript specs are 99% backward-compatible, there is no actual change in behavior, just wording. The rules in ES2015: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-rules-of-automatic-semicolon-insertion and ES2019: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-rules-of-automatic-semicolon-insertion are the same.